# Node.js error in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I using node:latest image. 
And get 
`ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: spawn /hobover_web_client/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant ENOENT`.
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /hobover_web_client
WORKDIR /hobover_web_client
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn
COPY package.json yarn.lock /hobover_web_client/

# install app dependencies   
RUN  rm -rf  node_modules/ && yarn install --ignore-scripts && yarn global add babel babel-cli webpack nodemon pngquant optipng recjpeg
ADD . /hobover_web_client
```

In docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
  hobover_web_client:
    container_name: hobover_web_client
    build: ./hobover_web_client
    command: yarn start    
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./hobover_web_client:/hobover_web_client
      - /hobover_web_client/node_modules
```

Build work successfully, but up cause an error.
How can I fix it if without docker it works?

Comment: Before the yarn install, you didn't copy package.json inside the container. Why?

Comment: Sorry, fixed, have copied from the wrong file, but error still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue the is mount of app and node_modules in the same directory. When you use below in docker-compose

```
  - ./hobover_web_client:/hobover_web_client
```

You are overshadowing the existing `node_modules`. So you need to use `NODE_PATH` to relocate your packages. Change your Dockerfile to below

```
FROM node:latest

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /hobover_web_client /node_modules
WORKDIR /hobover_web_client
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn NODE_PATH=/node_moudles
COPY package.json yarn.lock /hobover_web_client/

# install app dependencies   
RUN  yarn install --ignore-scripts && yarn global add babel babel-cli webpack nodemon pngquant optipng recjpeg
ADD . /hobover_web_client
```

Change your compose to below

```
version: '2'
  hobover_web_client:
    container_name: hobover_web_client
    build: ./hobover_web_client
    command: yarn start    
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./hobover_web_client:/hobover_web_client
      - /node_modules
```

So now your `/node_modules` goes to a anonymous volume, which you as such don't need and can remove, because the path is inside different folder

Comment: I added your noticed, but, unfortunately, problem left

Comment: I had a typo in `Dockerfile`. Change `ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn NODE_PATH=/node_moudles` to `ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=warn NODE_PATH=/node_modules`

Comment: I fixed typo and nothing changed

Comment: Post the out of `docker-compose logs` to your question